# Console.exe error every time shutting the Windows down?

Tags: windows-7

Whenever I attempt to shut down my Windows, i get the following error:

Console.exe : The instruction at 0x00000000 referenced memory at 0x00000000. The memory could not be written.

How do i fix it?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: @MichaelFrank : Windows 7 64-bit